# How to access the reader passed in the tokenStream method when overriding the methods of an Analyzer class in Apache Lucene 6.3

Tags: java, apache, lucene, analyzer

I am using Apache Lucene 6.3, and I need to extend an Analyzer class. In the older versions, two parameters were passed to the createComponent method, the first one indicated the field name for which analyzer was called and the second parameter represented the reader containing the main input text.

```
Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer() {
 @Override
  protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
    Tokenizer source = new FooTokenizer(reader);
    TokenStream filter = new FooFilter(source);
    filter = new BarFilter(filter);
    return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
  }
};
```

But in the newer version, only the field name is given as the function parameter.

```
 Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer() {
  @Override
   protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName) {
     Tokenizer source = new FooTokenizer(reader);
     TokenStream filter = new FooFilter(source);
     filter = new BarFilter(filter);
     return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
   }
   @Override
   protected TokenStream normalize(TokenStream in) {
     // Assuming FooFilter is about normalization and BarFilter is about
     // stemming, only FooFilter should be applied
     return new FooFilter(in);
   }
 };
```

My question is how should I access the reader in the input of `analyzer.tokenStream(fieldName,reader)` function to analyze the input text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *don't* access the reader in the `createComponents` method. Looks to me like you've found a documentation bug. `createComponents` sets up the analysis chain in preparation for the input being provided by `TokenStreamComponents.setReader`. In general, Tokenizers no longer take Readers as constructor arguments anymore.

I believe the tokenizer in this example should not have that argument, and should be:

```
@Override
 protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName) {
   Tokenizer source = new FooTokenizer();
   TokenStream filter = new FooFilter(source);
   filter = new BarFilter(filter);
   return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
 }
```

Comment: Yes, both codes above are from the original documentation. 
Removing the reader fixed the problem, I also had to use `this.input` in the custom tokenizer instead of the reader in the constructor.